# How open a specific screen show the detail of the notification in react native

Tags: push-notification, react-native

How to skip/open a specific screen based notification. Example: When a user clicks on the notification, the application should open and go directly to the notifications page instead of the home page.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but please add what work have you done ? what you have tried  ?

Comment: i writen the code to push notification with postman to my application i received the notification like an alert, now i want to click in this notification and after that show the detail of the notif @Rex5

Answer (score 0):

when i was using react-native-push-notification i mannage to get the text of my notification this way :

```
componentWillMount() {
 var _this = this;
 PushNotification.configure({
       onRegister: function(token) {
        _this.props.InitToken(token.token);
    },

 onNotification: function(notification) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if(!notification['foreground']){
          _this.props.InitNotif(notification['message']);
        }
      }, 1);
      PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        title: 'Notification with my name',
        message: notification['name'], // (required)
        date: new Date(Date.now()) // in 60 secs
      });
},

    // ANDROID ONLY: GCM Sender ID (optional - not required for local notifications, but is need to receive remote push notifications)
    senderID: "YourID",
});
 }
```

where

```
  _this.props.InitToken(token.token);
```

and

```
_this.props.InitNotif(notification['message']);
```

are redux based function that update your state with the notification token and message.  When you'r state is updated whith the notification message your can change route ou display the message on screen.

PS:

- i dont know if it was the good way but i was working
- componentWillMount() is depreciated.